# How to disable crash output in comet ml?

Tags: python, pytorch, comet, comet-ml

Every time my script is crashing I have such output:

```
COMET INFO:     sys.cpu.percent.43       : (0.0, 0.0)
COMET INFO:     sys.cpu.percent.44       : (1.8, 1.8)
COMET INFO:     sys.cpu.percent.avg      : (6.579545454545454, 6.579545454545454)
COMET INFO:     sys.gpu.0.free_memory    : (34089664512.0, 34089664512.0)
COMET INFO:     sys.gpu.0.gpu_utilization: (0.0, 0.0)
COMET INFO:     sys.gpu.0.total_memory   : (34089730048.0, 34089730048.0)
COMET INFO:     sys.gpu.0.used_memory    : (65536.0, 65536.0)
COMET INFO:     sys.load.avg             : (39.42, 39.42)
COMET INFO:     sys.ram.total            : (1621711745024.0, 1621711745024.0)
COMET INFO:     sys.ram.used             : (78552326144.0, 78552326144.0)
COMET INFO:   Other [count]:
COMET INFO:     offline_experiment: True
```

How can I disable it?

In comet-ml docs I found but probably it's not what I look for:

> by setting the environmental variable COMET_DISABLE_AUTO_LOGGING to 1

```
$ export COMET_DISABLE_AUTO_LOGGING=1                                                                                             
$ echo $COMET_DISABLE_AUTO_LOGGING 
1
```

But it didn't help me.

Comment: How did you set it and how did you verify that it is set? Also, there's always the backup option of setting it in the config file.